# How to get search result by a keyword from different table in MySQL for php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, multiple-select-query

In my project(online shopping website), I have a search box like flipkart website. After enter a search keyword the result of 4 table will show in a page.

```
Table : `tbl_product`
Field : `id`,`date`,`title`,`model_no`,`quantity`,`category_id`,`brand_id`,`color`,`size`

Table : `tbl_brand`
Field : `id`,`date`,`brand_name`,`category_id`,`description`

Table : `tbl_category`
Field : `id`,`date`,`category_title`, `description`

Table : `tbl_product_specification`
Field : `id`, `date`, `product_id`,`specification_title`
```

Now, I want to get search result of $keyword variable as:

```
`title`,`model_no` from `tbl_product`
`brand_name` from `tbl_brand`
`category_title` from `tbl_category`
`specification_title` from `tbl_product_specification`
```

I'm not good in MySQL SQL query. So, what SQL will complete this?

Comment: Would you mind giving it a go first? It really is the best way to learn. You'll need to do `SELECT (columns) FROM table1 INNER JOIN ON (table1.column = table2.column)`. You can add as many joins as you need to get all tables included. For example, joining between `tbl_product` and `tbl_brand`, the join could be `tbl_product AS p INNER JOIN tbl_brand AS b ON (p.brand_id = b.id)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
SELECT p.title, p.model_no,
    b.brand_name,
    c.category_title,
    s.specification_title
FROM tbl_product AS p
    LEFT JOIN tbl_brand AS b ON b.id = p.brand_id
    LEFT JOIN tbl_category AS c ON c.id = p.category_id
    LEFT JOIN tbl_product_specification AS s ON s.product_id = p.id
WHERE p.title LIKE 'keyword'
    OR p.model_no LIKE 'keyword'
    OR b.brand_name LIKE 'keyword'
    OR c.category_title LIKE 'keyword'
    OR s.specification_title LIKE 'keyword'
```

Comment: Required ORDER BY ??

Answer (score 0):

you should use union to join queries from different tables.
something like:

```
select title, model_no 
from tbl_product
where title like 'mykeyword'
union
select brand_name, ''
from tbl_brand
where brand_name like 'mykeyword'
select category_title, ''
from tbl_category
where category_title like 'mykeyword'
union 
select specification_title, ''
from tbl_product_specification
where specification_title like 'mykeyword'
order by 1
```

note that: 
each separate query must return the same number of columns as well as the same data types in the same sequence for more info about [Union](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp).

Comment: if i add GROUP BY product_id?

Comment: you only have product_id in one table.. you can't group by it!